# Assigning a method to an object as a variable

Tags: python, class, object, oop, methods

I wanted objects to call a certain method (the specific one being assigned in a variable) in their routine. I managed to do it with a dict and I also managed to do it by assigning the variable after object creation. Which way is better? Is there another cleaner way?

First way that works (dict):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = {
            'bear': self.bear,
            'boar': self.boar,
        }[funcin]
    
    def routine(self):
        print('fluff')
        self.func()

    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
    
    def boar(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a boar and I like fruits.')

bob = Foo('bob', 'bear')
mark = Foo('mark', 'boar')

bob.routine()
mark.routine()
```

Second way that worked (another line to assign):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
    
    def routine(self):
        print('fluff')
        self.func()

    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
    
    def boar(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a boar and I like fruits.')
    
Kona = Foo('Kona')
Kona.func = Kona.bear
John = Foo('John')
John.func = John.boar

Kona.routine()
John.routine()
```

Ways that didn't work:

```
# NameError: name 'bear' is not defined
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = self.funcin
    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
bob = Foo('bob', bear)
bob.func()

# NameError: name 'self' is not defined
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = funcin
    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
bob = Foo('bob', self.bear)
bob.func()

# NameError: name 'Kim' is not defined
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = funcin
    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
Kim = Foo('Kim', Kim.bear)
Kim.func()   

# TypeError: Foo.bear() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = funcin
    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
bob = Foo('bob', Foo.bear)
bob.func()
```

Comment: You'd need to make that a static method. Otherwise, there is no self.

Comment: The advantage of your first solution is that you've restricted what can be placed in `func`. If someone tries something other than a "bear" or a "boar", the error is immediate. The first method is also good if you are getting the animal from an external source such as a config file, where you need a name to method translation anyway (and have a greater need for error detection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use getattr():

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, funcin) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.func = getattr(self,funcin)
    
    def routine(self):
        print('fluff')
        self.func()

    def bear(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
    
    def boar(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a boar and I like fruits.')
```

If you don't need to perform additional (common) fluff, you could simply assign `self.routine = getattr(self,funcin)` and not even define the routine() function.

Answer (score 5):

The class's methods are available just as they are in a dict via the class's `__dict__` attribute. So in the first solution you presented, you could also define `self.func` like this:

```
self.func = Foo.__dict__[funcin].__get__(self)
```

So with `__dict__[funcin]` we retrieve the method from the class object, and with `__get__` we we get a function that has the correct `self` binding.

To make it even more generic so that you don't have to mention `Foo`:

```
self.func = self.__class__.__dict__[funcin].__get__(self)
```

Answer (score 3):

A common solution is class inheritance. There are multiple options from abstract base classes to mixins, but here is a simple start

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        
    def func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    def routine(self):
        print('fluff')
        self.func()

class Bear(Foo):
    
    def func(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a bear and I like honey.')
    
class Boar(Foo):
    
    def func(self):
        print(f'I, {self.name}, am a boar and I like fruits.')

bob = Bear('bob')
mark = Boar('mark')

bob.routine()
mark.routine()
```